# Accessing 'upper level name' of pandas multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I'm trying to learn how to use Pandas crosstab functionality but I can't find way to access 'upper level name' of multi-index dataframe that crosstab produces. Simple example:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}, orient='index')
df_test2 = pd.crosstab(df_test[0], df_test[1], margins=True)

print(df_test2.index.names)
```

Index.names gives me only '0' but want to get list like ['1','2','5'].

Comment: Your output does not create `MultiIndex`. Just 2 `Index`. '0' and '1' is the name of the row and column index. So what is your expected output?

Comment: I just posted an answer with the anatomy of a DataFrame to better understanding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataframe produces the following result:

[image]

```
>>> df_test2.columns.name
1

>>> df_test2.columns
Index([2, 5, 'All'], dtype='object', name=1)  # <- Note the 1 as name
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand that '1' was a name of column index. So this produced what I wanted:

```
test_list = df_test2.columns.to_list()
test_list.insert(0, df_test2.columns.name)
```

Comment: To produce what you expect you need to set `margins=False`.